Spring Boot and multiple JMS producers
I'm new to Spring Boot and JMS. I'm trying to setup multiple different JMS producers to be connected to two different ActiveMQ Artemis servers, but as soon as I add the second configuration I obtain this error:
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jmsTemplate in it.test.jms.producer.producer2 required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' in your configuration.

Any suggestion?
These are the files:
JmsConfiguration.java:
package it.test.data.config;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.SimpleMessageConverter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class JMSConfig {
    @Value("${jms.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jms.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${jms.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${jms.consumer.topic.name}")
    private String consumerTopicName;

    @Value("${jms.consumer.topic.clientid}")
    private String jmsClientId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Url: {}", this.url);
        log.info("user: {}", this.user);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.url, this.user, this.password);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory topicFactorySubscriptionDurable2(
            final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer
    ) {
        final var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setClientId(this.jmsClientId);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@link MessageConverter}
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jmsConverter() {
        log.info("jmsConverter");
        return new SimpleMessageConverter();
    }

}

JmsConfiguration2.java:
package it.test.data.config;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.SimpleMessageConverter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration2 {
    @Value("${spring.artemis.url2}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.artemis.user2}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${spring.artemis.password2}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.artemis.topic2.name}")
    private String consumerTopicName;

    @Value("${spring.artemis.topic2.clientid}")
    private String jmsClientId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Url: {}", this.url);
        log.info("user: {}", this.user);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory2() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.url, this.user, this.password);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory topicFactorySubscriptionDurable(
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory2
    ) {
        var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory( connectionFactory2);
        factory.setClientId(this.jmsClientId);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@link MessageConverter}
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jmsConverter2() {
        log.info("jmsConverter");
        return new SimpleMessageConverter();
    }

}

Producer1.java:
package it.test.data.producer;
    
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import it.test.model.ComponentMessage2;

@Component
public class Producer1 {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${spring.artemis.topic.topic1}")
    private String destinationQueue;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    }

    public void send(ComponentMessage1 componenteDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String msg = mapper.writeValueAsString(componenteDTO);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }
}

Producer2.java:
package it.test.data.producer;
    
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import it.test.model.ComponentMessage1;

@Component
public class Producer2 {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${spring.artemis.topic.topic2}")
    private String destinationQueue;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    }

    public void send(ComponentMessage1 componenteDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String msg = mapper.writeValueAsString(componenteDTO);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }
}

